# Не могу получить доступ к определенным каталогам(You don't have permission to access). Что это может быть, что настроить?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, битрикс, доступ, centos7

Ситуация такая.
После восстановления из резервной копии Битрикса, пропал доступ к некоторым каталогам. Причем закономерности не виду. Права доступа и владелец у каталог одинаковые

```
drwxrwx--- 8 bitrix bitrix 4096 Jan 12 09:46 /home/bitrix/www/company/
drwxrwx--- 2 bitrix bitrix 4096 Jan 18 11:32 /home/bitrix/www/for_them/
```

При обращении такой результат:
You don't have permission to access /for_them/ on this server. 
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server

Есть файл .access.php

```
$PERM["about"]["9"]="W";
$PERM["extranet"]["12"]="T_8";
$PERM["extranet"]["16"]="T_10";
$PERM["extranet"]["15"]="T_8";
$PERM["extranet"]["14"]="T_8";
$PERM["extranet"]["*"]="D";
$PERM["upload"]["14"]="T_8";
$PERM["upload"]["*"]="R";
$PERM["upload"]["5"]="T_8";
$PERM["/"]["13"]="T_10";
$PERM["/"]["12"]="R";
$PERM["/"]["*"]="D";
$PERM["/"]["2"]="D";
$PERM["company"]["9"]="T_9";
$PERM["pub"]["*"]="R";
$PERM["pub"]["5"]="T_8";
$PERM["online"]["*"]="R";
$PERM["desktop_app"]["*"]="R";
```

Думаю что проблема в нем. Но когда добавляю строку с for_them результата нет!
Выручайте! Что делать?

Comment: вместо абсолютно бессмысленных и неудобных как для людей так и для поисковых систем картинок лучше прикладывать текст. в данном случае — вывод команды `ls -ld /путь/к/каталогу /ещё/путь/к/каталогу ...`

Comment: selinux, вероятно, надо либо настроить либо отключить. логи-то его посмотрели?

Comment: Понял. учту по поводу картинок. Было просто лень по putty когда был открыть WinSCP)))
Лог посмотрел только я ничего не понимаю в нем...

Comment: проверьте настройки прав у инфоблоков через админку

Comment: С правами все в порядке.
Но когда указываю ссылку в виде /for_them/ , то permission to access /for_them/
А если явно /for_them/index.php , то все в порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из комментариев, сделал такой вывод, после восстановления бэкапа у вас рабочий `.htaccess` переименовало в `.htaccess.restore`, переименуйте его обратно в `.htaccess` и урлы должны начать нормально обрабатываться

Comment: Спасибо! Видимо именно в этом и была проблема!